# Variable in Spring Configuration

Tags: spring, configuration

I don't know anything about Spring, but the system I own will be using a Spring XML file. Is there any way to store a variable for example `myFileName = "myFile"` and then retrieve it from code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set every property of classes mentioned in the spring configuration files. (of course the class must have that property).

For example:

```
<bean class="com.example.MyBean">
  <property name="myFileName" value="mzFile" />
</bean>
```